# Filling <span /> moves tbody left

Tags: html, html-table

I've got a form inside a table that has some Javascript validation. The table tag is

```
<table style="padding-left:70px" align="left" cellpadding="10">
```

and a given row looks like this:

```
<tr id="email_row">
 <td align="right" valign="top">
  <label for="email">Email: *</label>
 </td>
 <td class="field_cell" valign="top">
  <input type="text" name="email" maxlength="80" size="30"><span class="error_field"></span>
 </td>
</tr>
```

If the user hits submit without this or other fields filled (or filled correctly), the span gets filled with an error message like "Invalid" or "Required." Unfortunately, doing this shifts the whole tbody over do the left (even though it is aligned left). Any suggestions?

FYI, I can only reproduce this problem in Chrome. Firefox and IE are working just fine.

Comment: Can you set up a test environment in JSFiddle or something. I can't do much with the code you provided. I don't see any CSS or anything. Inspect the error text and see if there are any paddings or margins being added from somewhere globally.

Comment: I fixed it! Unfortunately, my reputation won't allow me to post an answer for another three hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed!
The problem was that I had a row of text in the table with `colspan=2` that made the width of the table greater than the width of any of the other rows.
Adding text to the `<span>` elements increased the width of the second column, which in turn caused the first column to become smaller (since its cells were aligned to the right).

Comment: Pat yourself on the back and enjoy the moment. :)

Comment: You can accept your answer to indicate the question is resolved. Click on the tick.